# How can I append a different-sized matrix to another one on Python?

Tags: python, matrix

So, I spent some time looking around but did not quite find the answer I was looking for. I have two files of data, data1 and data2, that i've imported from txt's.

Each one is a matrix, data 1 has N1 rows and 2 columns, and data2 has N2 rows and 2 columns as well. Note that N1 is not equal to N2.
I would like to make a third matrix, data3, with the first two columns being the two from data1, and the two other columns being those from data2 . Also, they should have same length (that is, we must force N1 = N2 by eliminating the exceeding entries on the matrix that is larger).

To sum it up: In this case we should get a matrix N by 4, where N is min(N1,N2).

Anyone could help? :)

Comment: Looks like you got a pretty good answer to your question. Maybe you should accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your matrices are lists of lists, then this will combine them as you describe:

```
[data1[i] + data2[i] for i in range(min(len(data1), len(data2)))]
```

If you want to combine them straight from the files you can do this:

```
data1 = [line.strip() for line in open('data1.txt').readlines()]
data2 = [line.strip() for line in open('data2.txt').readlines()]
for first, second in zip(data1, data2):
    print('{0} {1}'.format(first, second))
```

If you don't want to read both files into memory you can do this:

```
data1 = open('data1.txt')
data2 = open('data2.txt')
while True:
    first = data1.readline().strip()
    second = data2.readline().strip()
    if not first or not second:
        break
    print('{0} {1}'.format(first, second))
```